# Get list of string dates between a given date range - Scala

Tags: java, list, scala, date, datetimeformatter

I am trying to get a list of string dates in Scala for a given range. Is there a direct/shorter way to achieve this?

```
val format = "yyyMMdd"
val startDate = "20200101"
val endDate = "20200131"
```

Expected Output = List(2020101,20200102, ....., 20200131)

Answer (score 0):

Ya...if you add dashes in the format you gave you can use `LocalData` to parse the date without using a date formatter to complicate it. e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
val startDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-01-01")

val endDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-01-31")
```

Then you can use `java.time.LocalDate.datesUntil` to generate the dates for you. After that there is some collection manipulation to do if you really want a `List` and some `String` manipulation to do for a date without dashes. This gets you most of the way.

```
startDate.datesUntil(endDate).collect(Collectors.toList()).asScala.map(date => date.toString)

List[String] = ArrayBuffer(2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03, ...).toList
```

Comment: You should use `DateTimeFormatter` instead of adding dashes.

Comment: I am not able to import java.time.datesUntil. Does it come under a diff package name?

Comment: My mistake. It's `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: I dont think there is a datesUntil in Java 8

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(getDateList("20200101", "20200110"));
        System.out.println(getDateList("20200101", "20200131"));
    }

    static List<String> getDateList(String strStartDate, String strEndDate) {
        // List to be populated with the desired strings
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // Formatter for the desired pattern
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");

        // Parse strings to LocalDate instances
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(strStartDate, formatter);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(strEndDate, formatter);

        // Loop starting with start date until end date with a step of one day
        for (LocalDate date = startDate; !date.isAfter(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
            result.add(date.format(formatter));
        }

        // Return the populated list
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[20200101, 20200102, 20200103,..., 20200110]
[20200101, 20200102, 20200103,..., 20200131]
```

### Solution using Java Stream API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(getDateList("20200101", "20200110"));
        System.out.println(getDateList("20200101", "20200131"));
    }

    static List<String> getDateList(String strStartDate, String strEndDate) {
        // Formatter for the input and desired pattern
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");

        // Parse strings to LocalDate instances
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(strStartDate, formatter);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(strEndDate, formatter);

        return Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusDays(1))
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate.plusDays(1)))
                .map(date -> date.format(formatter))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: @BasicLearner Can you possibly hand translate the Java code from this answer into Scala yourself? The algorithms and method calls certainly work in Scala too.