# Parse list of dates to list string in scala

Tags: java, scala, jodatime

Need to format date according to yyyyMMdd
below code generates a list of dates

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
import org.joda.time._

def getDates(startDate: String,endDate: String): Any = {
    val from = LocaDate.parse(startDate)
    val until = LocalDate.parse(endDate)
    val numberOfDays = Days.daysBetween(from, until).getDays()
    for (f<- 0 to numberOfDays) yield from.plusDays(f)
}

println(getDates("20200101","20200131"))
```

This returns -> Vector(2020-01-01,2020-01-31)

Need to convert returned Vector to List[String] in which elements are of format "yyyyMMdd"

Expected Output: List(20200101,....,20200131)

Comment: What have you tried? you only need a `map` and some format.

Comment: I tried this
val finalList = getDates("20200101","20200131")
finalList .map(_.toString)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez not able to do a .map on the returned list

Comment: Are you using Joda-Time? You may want to add the jodatime tag to your question or otherwise make clear for anyone wondering.

Comment: Probably because you made your method to return an **Any** instead of a `List[LocalDate]` ... again that would be basic scala knowledge, my advice would be to stop trying to make the code work without understanding the language and rather start reading some tutorial: https://docs.scala-lang.org/?_ga=2.259532302.508889943.1600136813-1166759874.1581082605

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you for your advice ... I have tried that as well, the output was List(2019-01-01, 2019-01-02) .. trying to reformat the List(20190101, 20190102)

Comment: Do not use `toString` use proper formatting, refer to the joda time documentation about how to do that.

Comment: Returning `Any` means that the code calling this method will not know what is the return type, which the compiler to check the methods you call. Either annotate the return type of the method as `Vector[LocalDate]` or don't and let type inference figure it out for you. Annotating types explicitly is usually advised for public and/or longer methods to facilitate the reader.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of string dates between a given date range - Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63891874/10819573)

Answer (score 2):

If the `getDates()` input is 2 strings, and the desired output is `List[String]`, then I don't really see any reason to use the old and outdated Joda Time library. The `java.time` library is more recent and feature-full.

It also offers the `datesUntil()` method, which does pretty much what you want, except that it returns a `java.util.stream.Stream`, which is a bit of a pain because the transition from Java `Stream` to Scala `List` will depend on the Scala version you're running.

Here, for example, is how you might do it in Scala 2.13.x:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import scala.jdk.StreamConverters.StreamHasToScala

def getDates(startDate:String, endDate:String):List[String] = {
  val pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
  LocalDate.parse(startDate, pattern)
           .datesUntil(LocalDate.parse(endDate, pattern).plusDays(1))
           .toScala(List)
           .map(_.format(pattern))
}
```

You'll notice that there is no checking for valid input format, so this is for demonstration and not production-worthy code.